# using flightCtrl under NO GPS environment

Tags: c++, dji-sdk

I'm developing osdk application for Matrice600Pro.

I want to use flightCtrl under poor GPS environment (ex:under bridge)

I have some questions about this:

1. Can I use only HORIZONTAL_ANGLE or HORIZONTAL_ANGULAR_RATE flags for horizontal control? Does this mean I have to calculate UAV angle from goal speed and UAV weight? (I want to control UAV speed by meter/sec unit)
2. When I wrote code like below, my drone rotated well under good GPS condition, but not under bridge. I only want to rotate drone with this code:

```
uint8_t ctrl_flag = ( Control::VERTICAL_VELOCITY | Control::HORIZONTAL_VELOCITY | Control::YAW_ANGLE | Control::HORIZONTAL_BODY | Control::STABLE_ENABLE);
Control::CtrlData data(ctrl_flag, 0, 0, 0, targetYaw); 
gVehicle->control->flightCtrl(data);
```

Is `Control::HORIZONTAL_VELOCITY` flag causing this?
Does this code work well with other flag under poor gps condition? (i.e.:HORIZONTAL_ANGLE)
(I cannot test now )